# mmap-like algorithm using fseek

Tags: c, mmap, fread, memory-mapped-files, fseek

So my idea is to be able to read small parts of a file at any offset as if it were memory mapped, but with using fseek/fread.  Most of the time it would be sequential but needs to have the ability to read from any arbitrary offset into the file.  It also needs a small buffer of say 64KB to read into and fill up once the current reading offset is near the end (possibly from another thread using something like double buffering), which can also be intelligently offset back into when possible, not just a naive fseek fread.

Is there an existing library/algorithm that handles this or is it something that I have to write all myself.  My googleing did not find much.

Comment: why not memory mapped file? Is that not closest to what you need at near zero work? I mean - it is probably easier to write a "sequential access" abstraction over a mmapped file than writing a fseek abstraction for a mmap file replacement.

Comment: I think is almost impossible to beat the kernel performance of memory mapped files. The kernel has more information about hardware and available RAM and can use the virtual address space to achieve a user-space transparent implementation.